# How to use "Both"

Tags: grammar

How to use *both* in sentences when we have "and"?

For example:

*both of X and Y are letters.*
Or
   *both X and Y are letters?*

Comment: "Both X and Y are letters" or "Both of them are letters."

Answer (score 2):

From the [Cambridge Online Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/both), your second sentence is correct in this context:

> We use both … and to emphasise the link between two things. This makes a stronger connection than and alone:
>
> > *Both Britain and France agree on the treaty. (stronger link than Britain and France agree on the treaty.)*

'Both of' should only be used prior to an object pronoun, such as "both of them".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about this please: _I know both of you and your brother._?" Or _I know both of Kate and John._?

Comment: Hi, neither of those sentences work for me; the correct forms would be: _I know both you and your brother_ and _I know both Kate and John_.